# how to use tee without pipes

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

I want to redirect a program's stdout and stderr to a file and print it to screen at the same time, the obvious solution is to use *tee*:

```
./my_program 2>&1 | tee log_file
```

However, because *tee* isn't activate until the program finishes execution, I can't see the program output in real-time.

Is there a way to have the same effect while being able to see what a program prints in real-time ?

Comment: See this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe

Comment: Are you sure you need to blame `tee`? isn't `my_program` to blame instead because of buffering? E.g., compare `{ echo a; sleep 2; echo b; } | tee` and `{ echo a; sleep 2; echo b; } | grep . | tee`.

Comment: It's incorrect to say that `tee` isn't "activated" until `my_program` terminates. In a pipeline, all programs run concurrently. So, as gnourf said, the delay is due to buffering in `my_program`.

Comment: Also have a look at [BashFAQ/009](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/009).

Comment: @anubhava is correct, the problem isn't in `my_program` as I'm flushing output frequently, adding `unbuffer` so my command would be `unbuffer ./my_program 2>&1 | tee log_file` gave the desired effect. - Thank you.

Comment: If you have solved the issue, please answer your own question with the relevant information and accept your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, redirect to a file directly and use `tail -f` to follow the output.

#### First Terminal Window

```
./my_program 2>&1 > log_file
```

#### Second Terminal Window

```
tail -f log_file
```

Comment: A good start, but since I'm running several programs one after the other and each is writing to their own log file, this isn't practical in my case.

Comment: @user1426692, How would you have done it with `tee`? You'd still be viewing several outputs at once, no?

Comment: @user1426692 It's not merlin's fault that you didn't ask your actual quesiton.